# Remove duplicate function block using 'awk'/Python (Generic solution)

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk

I have a text file containing several function blocks and some of them are duplicates. I want to create a new file which contains only unique Function blocks. e.g.
input.txt (I have updated the example):

```
Func (a1,b1) abc1
{
xyz1;
    {
        xy1;
    }

xy1;
}

Func (a2,b2) abc2
{
xyz2;
    {
        xy2;
        rst2;
    }

xy2;
}

Func (a1,b1) abc1
{
xyz1;
    {
        xy1;
    }

xy1;
}

Func (a3,b3) abc3
{
xyz3;
    {
        xy3;
        rst3;
        def3;
    }

xy3;
}
    Func (a1,b1) abc1
{
xyz1;
    {
        xy1;
    }

xy1;
}
```

And want to have output.txt as:

```
Func (a1,b1) abc1
{
xyz1;
    {
        xy1;
    }

xy1;
}

Func (a2,b2) abc2
{
xyz2;
    {
        xy2;
        rst2;
    }

xy2;
}

Func (a3,b3) abc3
{
xyz3;
    {
        xy3;
        rst3;
        def3;
    }

xy3;
}
```

I found one solution using `awk` to remove duplicate line, something like:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' input.txt > output.txt
```

But the issue is that the above solution matches only single line not a text block. I wanted to combine this `awk` solution with the regex to match a single function block:  `'/^FUNC(.|\n)*?\n}/'`

But I was not able to do that. Any suggestion/solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for their solutions. They were correct as per the example I posted, but my actual task was a bit more generic. I found a generic solution in Python, as the above mentioned response did not work perfectly(may be because my knowledge in bash is limited).
My generic solution using Pythons is as follows:

```
import re
import os

testFolder = "./Path"

#Usage: Remove duplicate function block from one or more .txt files available in testFolder

#Iterating through the list of all the files available
for testFilePath in os.listdir(testFolder):
    if testFilePath.endswith(".txt"):
        #Extracting path for each text file found
        inputFile = open (testFolder + "/" + testFilePath, "r")

        #Creating a reduced folder in the output path
        outputPath = testFolder + "/Reduced"
        if not os.path.exists(outputPath):
            os.makedirs(outputPath)
        outputFile = open (outputPath + "/" + testFilePath, "w")

        #Reading all the content into a single string
        fileContent = inputFile.read()

        #Pattern for matching a Function block. Pattern matches multiple lines
        pattern = re.compile('(^FUNC(.|\n)*?\n})*',re.M)

        # Creating a list of function blocks
        funcList = pattern.findall(fileContent)
        #Creating a list of unique function block, thus removing duplicate data
        uniqueFuncList = set(funcList)

        #Writing each Function block to the output file separeted by a new line
        for element in uniqueFuncList:
            outputFile.write(element[0] + "\n\n") 
        inputFile.close()
        outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '$1=="Func"{ f=!seen[$NF]++ } f' file
Func (a1,b1) abc1
{
xyz1;
    {
        xy1;
    }

xy1;
}

Func (a2,b2) abc2
{
xyz2;
    {
        xy2;
        rst2;
    }

xy2;
}

Func (a3,b3) abc3
{
xyz3;
    {
        xy3;
        rst3;
        def3;
    }

xy3;
}
```

The above just assumes that every Func definition is on it's own line and that line ends with the function name.

All it does is look for a "Func" line and then set a flag `f` to true if this is the first time we've seen the function name at the end of the line and false otherwise (using the common awk idiom `!seen[$NF]++` which you were already using in your question but named your array `a[]`). Then it prints the current line if `f` is true (i.e. you're following the Func definition of a previously unseen function name) and skips it otherwise (i.e. you're following the Func definition of a function name that had been seen previously).

Comment: woauw still so sharp in your code. Very efficient and short code. Add maybe some comment for the requester who is new in awk and due to the fact that you use lot of guru's shortcut here

Answer (score 2):

if your code blocks are separated with empty lines, you can define record separator (and output record separator)...

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!a[$0]++' input.txt > output.txt
```

**NB.** Works on toy examples, however this is fragile since any empty line in the code block will break the logic.  Similarly you can't depend on curly brace since it may appear in the code block as well.

**UPDATE**

For the updated input this may work better

```
$ awk -v ORS='\n\n' '{record=($1~/^Func/)?$0:record RS $0} 
    /^}/ && !a[record]++{print record} '
```

here we define the record that starts with a "Func" keyword and end with a curly brace on the first position. Accumulate the lines for the record and print with done.  Set the ORS to have empty lines between records.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have added en example closer to what I have

Comment: you may need a parser to do this robustly, especially if you also have free form comments and need to handle curly braces and "Func" keyword in the comment section.

Comment: I have removed all comments from the file to make it easier.

Comment: dangerous with inside code that can match the end also

Comment: @karakfa, can you please explain your solution so that I can modify it to my needs? i am new to awk. Thanks

Comment: The updated solution created 100mb txt file! Some sort of repetitive data is being output!

Comment: did it work with the sample input file?  If so, the heuristic doesn't work with real input, which is most likely different from the sample...

Comment: It won't work with the sample since the 2nd occurrence of the abc1 function has it's first line indented and so isn't an exact string match for the first occurrence of that same function.

Comment: Function stop on closing brace starting a line but we don't know format exactly. I like the way you shortcut and create new "record"

Answer (score 1):

As OP changed the requirement and examples so I have re-written the code, could you please try and let me know if this helps you(reading Input_file 2 times here).

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /Func/ && !a[$0]++{gsub(/^ +/,"");!b[$0]++;next} FNR!=NR && /Func/{flag=($0 in b)?1:"";delete b[$0]} flag'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner solution for solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR && /Func/ && !a[$0]++{
  gsub(/^ +/,"");
  !b[$0]++;
  next}
FNR!=NR && /Func/{
  flag=($0 in b)?1:"";
  delete b[$0]}
flag
'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Comment: can your explain your solution, maybe I can alter it to my requirements?

Comment: assuming there is no  `}` in code and sample show it is not the case

Comment: @tanzil, please check my edited code and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

adapt this code for your real purpose (don't know the exact protocol and format of the language in sample). Code is self commented

```
awk '
   # at every new function
   /^Func[[:space:]]*[(]/ {
     # print last function if keeped
     if ( Keep ) print Code
     # new function name
     Name=$NF
     # define to keep or avoid (keep if not yet in the list)
     Keep = ! ( Name in List)
     # put fct name in list
     List[ Name ]
     # clean code in memory
     Code = ""
     }
     # at each line, load the line into the code
      # if code is not empty, add old code + new line
     { Code = ( Code ? Code "\n" : "" ) $0 }

   # at the end, print last code if needed
   END { if ( Keep ) print Code }  
   ' sample.txt
```